# Return value corrupt when C++11 application uses non-C++11 library

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, shared-libraries, clang

I've got a library that was compiled without C++11 flags (-std=c++11) and an application linking to that library which was built with -std=c++11. It calls a function in the library and the program then crashes much deeper within the library. I've found that the disassembly of the function (which is just a simple function that returns a pointer within a class) where the crash occurs the is different between when the callstack originates from this program as opposed to the library's test program which also wasn't built with C++11 flags.

The OS is OS X Mountain Lion and the compiler is Clang++.

Why is there an incapability between the C++11 app and non-C++11 library and also when is the disassembly generated when the differing generated code is inside the library and thus should be the same?

The two different disassemblies:

```
TestApplication`Core::GetPointer() const at System.h:xxx:
0x100009690:  pushq  %rbp
0x100009691:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x100009694:  movq   %rdi, -8(%rbp)
0x100009698:  movq   -8(%rbp), %rdi
0x10000969c:  movq   64(%rdi), %rax  ;<-------Difference
0x1000096a0:  popq   %rbp
0x1000096a1:  ret    

Lib1Prototype`Core::GetPointer() const at System.h:xxx:
0x100019c10:  pushq  %rbp
0x100019c11:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x100019c14:  movq   %rdi, -8(%rbp)
0x100019c18:  movq   -8(%rbp), %rdi
0x100019c1c:  movq   40(%rdi), %rax  ;<------Difference
0x100019c20:  popq   %rbp
0x100019c21:  ret
```

Comment: Well, does the library expose any part of the standard library in its interface? Does it have a C interface?

Comment: It's a pretty large library with a large interface so I haven't reviewed every function signature but it does appear to avoid exposing the standard library in its public interface but it definitely uses it internally (headers contain private vectors and maps). Its interface is C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the x86-64 ABI used by OS X, the first argument to a function is passed in `%rdi`, and the function's return value is passed in `%rax`.*  So this function takes a pointer to some data structure, and returns the 64-bit value contained starting at offset 64 or 40, depending on how the function was compiled.

So you need to look at the header file that defines that data structure.  It's defining the data structure differently depending on whether you're compiling as C++11.  Maybe there's something obvious, like a `#ifdef` that you know is defined differently.  Or maybe there's a member whose type is defined differently.  If you can't figure it out, edit your question and paste in the definition of the data structure that's being passed (by pointer) to the `Core::GetPointer` function.

Comment: There's no #ifdef checking the language version in this class's declaration but there is a private member variable that uses std::vector. The Standard C++ Library linked would be different between the language versions so perhaps that's the cause?

Comment: It's certainly possible.  You could inspect the `<vector>` header file to try to figure it out... or just log the `sizeof` each member of the class/struct, compiled each way, to see which member has a different size.

Comment: It turns out to be std::map (which was used by one classes that Core inherits). There's a 24 byte difference in the size of it.

Comment: @akai : Welcome to C++ and the world of binary interfaces. ;-] (Hint: never mix and match.)